# Python web-scraping return url using Gazpacho

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, gazpacho

How can I return the URL text from item using gazpacho?

```
from gazpacho import get, Soup


page = 0
id = 0

try:
    while True:
        page += 1
        url = f'https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/regiao-serrana/petropolis/imoveis?o={page}'

        html = get(url)
        soup = Soup(html)

        offers = soup.find('div', {'class': 'fnmrjs-1 gIEtsI'}, strict=True)


        for item in offers:
            id += 1
            title = item.find('h2', {'class': 'sc-1mbetcw-0 eJfLou sc-ifAKCX jyXVpA'}, strict=True).text
            price = item.find('div', {'class': 'aoie8y-0 hRScWw'}, strict=True).text
            location = item.find('span', {'class': 'sc-7l84qu-1 ciykCV sc-ifAKCX dpURtf'}, strict=True).text
            #link = ????
            print(str(id), "-",title , price, location , link)
            
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted using CTRL + C')
```

Also the way i found to run on all pages adding +1 value is not good because if i reach a value that does not exist it start looping on first page, I'd appreciate if you guys have any idea to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab the follow links you might want to search for all `li` tags and extract the anchors.

For example:

```
from gazpacho import get, Soup

url = f'https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/regiao-serrana/petropolis/imoveis?o=1'
offers = Soup(get(url)).find(
    'li',
    {"class": "sc-1fcmfeb-2 juiJqh"},
    partial=True,
)
follow_links = [
    o.find("a").attrs.get("href") for o in offers if o.find("a")
]
print("\n".join(follow_links))
```

Output:

```
https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/imoveis/casa-845800716
https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/imoveis/casa-para-locacao-15-min-a-pe-do-centro-historico-845797561
https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/imoveis/apartamento-de-quarto-e-sala-no-centro-791808170
https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/comercio-e-industria/self-storage-guarda-moveis-estoque-e-documentos-548419653
https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/imoveis/apartamento-841458075
https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/imoveis/apartamento-02-quartos-sendo-01-suite-mosela-petropolis-rj-805359360
https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/imoveis/cobertura-duplex-com-2-vagas-proximo-ao-centro-petropolis-rj-818116827
https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/imoveis/condominio-pedra-do-retiro-759441464
and much more ...
```

EDIT:

To solve the problem with looping over the same pages again, just grab the total number of available pages and use this in the `range()`.

Putting all of this together, you might have something like this:

```
from gazpacho import get, Soup

base_url = f'https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/regiao-serrana/petropolis'
s = Soup(get(f"{base_url}/imoveis?o=1"))

total_pages = int(
    "".join(
        i.strip().split()[-1] for i
        in s.find("p", {"color": "dark"})
        if "Página" in i.text
    )
)


for page in range(1, total_pages + 1):
    s = Soup(get(f"{base_url}/imoveis?o={page}"))
    offers = s.find('li', {"class": "sc-1fcmfeb-2 juiJqh"}, partial=True)

    follow_links = [
        o.find("a").attrs.get("href") for o in offers if o.find("a")
    ]
    descriptions = [
        o.find("h2", {"color": "dark"})[0].text for o in offers if o.find("h2")
    ]
    prices = [
        o.find("p", {"class": "sc-ifAKCX eoKYee"}).text
        if o.find("p", {"class": "sc-ifAKCX eoKYee"}) else "N/A"
        for o in offers
    ]

    search_results = zip(descriptions, follow_links, prices)
    bar = '-' * max(len(l) for l in follow_links)

    print(
        "\n".join(
            f"{desc}\nPrice: {price}\nURL: {link}\n{bar}" for
            desc, link, price in search_results
        )
    )
```

Output:

```
Casa de condomínio à venda com 5 dormitórios em Corrêas, Petrópolis cod:2610
Price: R$ 2.000.000
URL: https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/imoveis/casa-de-condominio-a-venda-com-5-dormitorios-em-correas-petropolis-cod-2610-821071980
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Apartamento todo Reformado no Centro de Petrópolis
Price: N/A
URL: https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/imoveis/apartamento-todo-reformado-no-centro-de-petropolis-845056149
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Casa
Price: N/A
URL: https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/imoveis/casa-845800716
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Casa para locação (15 min. a pé do centro histórico)
Price: R$ 749.990
URL: https://rj.olx.com.br/serra-angra-dos-reis-e-regiao/imoveis/casa-para-locacao-15-min-a-pe-do-centro-historico-845797561
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
and more ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother! You made me realize my mistakes. The script you provided had an error on getting descriptions so i changed to .attrs.get("title")

Comment: the error i mentioned comment before is:

o.find("h2", {"color": "dark"})[0].text for o in offers if o.find("h2")
TypeError: 'Soup' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Just realized that prices does not correspond to link. I m trying to analyze it, but if you have any idea.